# Facebook Sharing not Working When Facebook Application is installed on Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

There are two ways of sharing in Facebook. One if Facebook Native Application is installed then it shows WebDialog for sharing within the application and if Facebook Native Application is installed then it navigates you from your application to Facebook Application to share your content. But When I am trying with FB App installed it shows an error .
[image: Facebook Error]

I am using this code for sharing using Share Dialog:

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
if(error) {
  NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"result %@", results);
}
```

}];

One more thing if I try :

```
[FBDialogs presentMessageDialogWithLink:params.link name:params.name caption:params.caption description:params.description picture:params.picture clientState:nil handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
if(error) {

    NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
}
else {

    NSLog(@"result %@", results);
}
```

}];

It does nothing It will not navigate to Facebook application.

So Finally I have two question :

- Why Sharing is not working using First set of code?
- Why second set of codes not working for ShareDialog?

I will highly thankful to you for any help.

Comment: do you test with real device? and what nslog or error description please put this as well.

Comment: Yes I am using iPad 4 Retina ,I place the screen shot from Real Device and in simulator you can't install Facebook application.

There is no Log for that , It just shows the error that I attached as screenshot when you shared through application.
By using WebDialog it works .

Comment: plese check your facebook app id setting properly or your url schemes having your fb id like fb040450480540?

Comment: Yea I checked it , Its Correct.

Comment: see: i think there is technical fault  https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=681732441921695